# After-blessing for water that was covered by wine that was covered by bread

Tags: blessing, bentching, grapes-wine, meal-seudah, drinking

If one drank wine, and then drank water or juice, and forgot to bentch for what he drank, or if he did not need to bentch for the wine because it was from Kiddush, and then he had a meal right afterwards and he recited Birkas Hamazon, would he not  need to bentch for the water, since the blessing for wine covers all other drinks, only in this case the blessing for wine was covered by Birkas Hamazon?

Comment: If you drink water and then wine, wouldn't you have to make an after-blessing for each?

Answer (score 2):

According to [Shulchan Aruch HaRav](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh_HaRav%2C_Orach_Chayim.272.13?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) one would still need to make a brocha achronah on the water.